# Checking time between hour range in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, timestamp-with-timezone

I want to check if the time i have is between 10pm-6am or between 12pm-6am 
i wrote the code for the same and code is working though but i am not sure if it is gonna still work for the all the cases. 
i also feel that the code should be efficient and simple enough to solve this problem.

I have provided the timezone(number e.g. 3 means +3) and timing(String "10to6" or "12to6" or "off")
the timezone of my server is GMT.

> Code:

```
function(timezone, timing) {
    var utcDate = new Date();
    var udate = utcDate.getTime();
    udate += (Number(timezone) * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    var userDate = new Date(udate);
    if (userDate.getHours() > 0 && userDate.getHours() < 22) {
        var firstStart = new Date(userDate.getFullYear(), userDate.getMonth(), userDate.getDate() - 1, 22, 0, 0);
        var firstEnd = new Date(userDate.getFullYear(), userDate.getMonth(), userDate.getDate(), 6, 0, 0);
        var secondStart = new Date(userDate.getFullYear(), userDate.getMonth(), userDate.getDate() - 1, 24, 0, 0);
        var secondEnd = new Date(userDate.getFullYear(), userDate.getMonth(), userDate.getDate(), 6, 0, 0);
    } else {
        var firstStart = new Date(userDate.getFullYear(), userDate.getMonth(), userDate.getDate(), 22, 0, 0);
        var firstEnd = new Date(userDate.getFullYear(), userDate.getMonth(), userDate.getDate() + 1, 6, 0, 0);
        var secondStart = new Date(userDate.getFullYear(), userDate.getMonth(), userDate.getDate(), 24, 0, 0);
        var secondEnd = new Date(userDate.getFullYear(), userDate.getMonth(), userDate.getDate() + 1, 6, 0, 0);
    }
    if (timing == "off") {
        return true;
    }
    if (timing == "10to6") {
        if (udate > firstStart.getTime() && udate < firstEnd.getTime()) {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (timing == "12to6") {
        if (udate > secondStart.getTime() && udate < secondEnd.getTime()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

if there is any other better approach or a way to prove that this is working all the time,any ideas are most welcome.

Comment: Use http://momentjs.com/ if you want a simpler approach.

Comment: as mentioned by @James, using [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) will provide you a better approach as this library already have various inbuilt functions related date and time which will make your task easier.

Comment: i could not find a way to do it in moment.
i prefer not to use libraries for this as i want to understand how it can be done in javascript std if possible